# Video Module with Drupal 7 custom form

Tags: drupal, video, drupal-7

How can I use video module drupal 7 version with Custom form to create a field behave exactly the field on the node form? To do so I created a form with video field type but its not displaying anything

```
$form['file'] = array(
    '#type' => 'video',
    '#name' => 'files[]',
    '#title' => t('Upload some videos'),
    '#attributes' => array('multiple' => 'multiple'),
);
```

I used this From the test file of video.The filename is. `VideoField.test`

Comment: I am looking for a solution for the same task, but unfortunately did'n find any yet. Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: unfortunately I didn't find anything to add new field to custom form. But i found way to include a node's video field to custom form. here is the link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12854424/add-cck-field-to-custom-form-in-drupal-7/